# access current attributes in d3 functions

Tags: d3.js

`circle` is an array of four `d3` circles.

```
     circle
        .attr( "cy", function(){ this.attr("cy") + 10*input_data.pitch });
```

This fails. How can I access the individual attributes in anonymous functions like above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside your function, `this` is an [Element](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-745549614) per the [W3C DOM API](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/). So it’s just `this.getAttribute("cy")`.

Two more things: you forgot to `return` a value. And since attribute values are strings, you’ll need to coerce them to number before you can add another number. Otherwise your number will get coerced to a string and then the two strings will be concatenated: `"10" + 2` is `"102"`, not `12`.

So, like this:

```
circle.attr("cy", function() {
  return +this.getAttribute("cy") + 10 * input_data.pitch;
});
```

All that said, it’s generally not idiomatic D3 to pull data back out of DOM attributes. (It’s slow and you have coercion and serialization problems since DOM attributes can only be strings.) So I would recommend looking for a way to do this based on data, and limit yourself to data-driven documents… not document-driven data!